# $2{\pi}\sin{nx} = 2{\pi} -x$ has $2018$ different solutions

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

$n$ is a positive integer. If $2{\pi}\sin{nx} = 2{\pi} -x$, where $ 0{\le}{x}<2\pi$, has exactly $2018$ different solutions, what is $n$?

A short hint will be good enough. Thanks!

Comment: One way (not the easiest i guess) : What are the variations of $x \mapsto 2\pi\left(\sin\left(nx\right)-1\right)+x$ ?

Comment: It is 2022 already. What did you try all these years?

Comment: Use [Desmos](http://www.Desmos.com/calculator) enter $y=2\pi\sin1x$ and $y=2\pi-x$ See that? Change the 1 to a 2. Then 3. Do you see the pattern and do you see why this is happening? That's your hint. This question will probably be closed soon. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a general  sine-wave is given by:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{a}\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\tag1$$

We know that $\omega=2\pi\text{f}=\frac{2\pi}{\text{T}}$, where $\text{f}$ is the frequency and $\text{T}$ is the period. So, one period has a time of:

$$\text{T}=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}\tag2$$

---

We can see that your line $2\pi-x$ has a negative slope so the line is trending down when $x$ increases. The period of your sine function is:

$$\text{T}=\frac{2\pi}{\text{n}}\tag3$$

And because the line is trending down we get **two** solutions per period to the equation:

$$2\pi\sin\left(\text{n}x\right)=2\pi-x\tag4$$

> So: when we want $2018$ different solutions, we need $\text{n}=\dots$

Comment: yeah thanks! I was already thinking about the graphs actually, but I just felt like given the 2pi - x on the RHS, there would be some trick with it

Comment: @A.Lim you're welcome!